# bonjour/mdns repeater?

Tags: airplay, bonjour, dns

I would like to put my wifi network and my wired network (in a small office) on separate vlans to cut down on broadcasts/multicasts on the wifi.
(right now it's all in one big vlan, and it's getting out of hand.)

One problem that's come up is that wireless devices cannot see the Bonjour announcements of wired devices if they are on different VLANs.  eg. a wired printer, or apple tv for airplay...

It seems potentially possible to setup a mdns/bonjour repeater that sits on both networks and let's some announcements flow back and forth..

Has anyone attempted this sort of setup?

Ideally I would filter/whitelist which devices would be echo'd to both networks...

Answer (score 3):

If you have a Linux/BSD computer connected to both the networks, you can use the mDNS responder [Avahi](http://avahi.org/) to reflect the bonjour traffic between the two networks.

The relevant Avahi configuration (`avahi-daemon.conf`) is a section like this:

```
[reflector]
enable-reflector=yes
```

Here's another relevant SE thread with answers:

[What, exactly, is required to make Airplay work across VLANs?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/5954/what-exactly-is-required-to-make-airplay-work-across-vlans)

I have successfully used Avahi on my Soekris router (running FreeBSD) for several years to solve this problem.

Comment: I've found that, but I think I'd prefer something more surgical.  I don't want to reflect all mDNS out all ports (avahi's default behavior)..  I would prefer to filter and selectively copy.. (working on that using scapy)